# Arrangements of roots in recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

I came across the recurrence relation $T(k)-7T(k-2)+6T(k-3)=0$ where $T(0)=8,T(1)=6 $and $T(2)=22$.
I found the roots of the characteristic equation to be $1,-3,2$ and the constants to be $1,2,5$. So, the solution  $T(k)=5(1)^k+2(-3)^k+1(2)^k$. But my book states the solution to be $ T(k)=5+2(2)^k+(-3)^k$. I can notice that this has been obtained by just assigning different constants to different roots. So, my question is how do we determine which constants are to be assigned to which root?

Comment: Have you **checked** whether (i) your formula works for $k=0,1,2$, (ii) the book's formula works for $k=0,1,2$?

Comment: Mine doesn't work for T=1 ...but why???

Comment: Probably an arithmetic error?

Comment: I don't think it's an arithmetic error, for I got the same constants and roots as the book.

Comment: You have to pair each "constant" with the correct root.

Comment: It's like they have assigned a different serial number to the roots from me

Comment: What makes them "correct"??

Comment: What makes 1 the first root, 2 the second root and -3 the third root???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You properly found the roots of the characteristic equation. So
$$T_k=c_1 (1)^k+c_2 (2)^k+c_3 (-3)^k=c_1 +c_2 (2)^k+c_3 (-3)^k$$ Now apply the conditions
$$8=c_1+c_2+c_3$$
$$6=c_1+2c_2-3c_3$$
$$22=c_1+4c_2+9c_3$$

This seems to be easy to solve.